# Max and min of a function over a set

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, constraints

I have to find max and min of the function $f(x, y) = xy (x+y)$ over the set

$$H = \{(x, y) \in [0, 1]^2; x+y \leq 1\}$$

*attempts*

Forst of all, I showed that $H$ is bounded (since it's a triangle, I can always find a ball $B$ with radius large enough to contain $H$), and it's also closed because $\partial H \in H$. Hence it's compact, whence I can apply Weierstrass theorem which guarantees the existence of max and min (absolute).

Now I have to study both the critical point inside $H$ and on the boundary.

Inside $H$: I computed the gradiend:

$$\nabla f = (y(2x+y), x(x+2y)) = (0, 0)$$

This means that $(x, y) = (0, 0)$ is the only solution.

But this point is not internal, it's a boundary point. Can I then conclude there is no max/min inside $H$, and pass on the evaluation on the boundary?

In this case (without using Lagrange multipliers), I would evaluate $f(x, y)$ in the restriction $y \leq 1-x$ like

$$f(x, 1-x) = x(1-x)(x + 1-x) = x(1-x)$$

Now it's like a one dimensional function, and $f'(x) = 0$ for $x = 1/2$.

Due to the constraint, then $y = 1-x = 1/2$ too, hence I have $(1/2, 1/2)$ and $(0, 0)$ as candidates.

$$f(0, 0) = 0$$
$$f(1/2, 1/2) = \frac{1}{4}$$

Which means $(0, 0)$ is an absolute min and $(1/2, 1/2)$ is absolute max.

Am I corret? Am I wrong? Did I leave something out?
THank you!

Answer (score 2):

Take a moment to reason about your answers.

Can $f$ be negative on $H$? Surely not. So if you've found a point where $f=0$, then surely you've found *a* minimum (in fact, it's both axes).

Now, is $f$ symmetrical in $x$ and $y$? So, look along the axis of symmetry (the line $x=y$). If you're off-axis and travel along the line $x+y=k$ towards the axis, what happens to $xy$ - does it necessarily get bigger until it reaches a maximum on the axis at $x=y=k/2$? So, is your maximum going to be along $x=y$ somewhere?

So when $x=y$, $f(x,y)=2x^3$ and takes its maximum of $1/4$ when $x=y=1/2$.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed what I was missing was the fact that I can have min for every point for the forms $(x, 0)$ and $(0, y)$. Because of this, can I say there is no absolute min, but just local ones?

Comment: Because $f=0$ along all of $x=0$ and $y=0$ and $f>0$ everywhere else in its domain, I'd say the axes are all *global* minimum *points*, and $f$ has a global minimum *value* of 0. $x=y=1/2$ is the *strict* global maximum point and $f$ has a *strict* maximum value of $1/4$. Maybe your usage of *absolute* is confusing you between points and values - there is no need for the point at which a function takes its global extreme value to be unique. A local minimum means there *may* be strictly smaller values elsewhere but none nearby - so global extreme points are always also local extreme points.

Comment: Perhaps we use "absolute" as a synonym of "global"